# Disk/Washer Method Problem with Volume of Solids of Revolution

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How do I find the volume of a shape made by $$f(x)=x^2+2$$ but bounded by $y=4$. It is rotated around $y=-1$

I just need to know how (step-by-step) to setup the integral. Also is there a method of making partitions to find the area?

Much Appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you have the bound correctly? Don't you mean $y=4$?

Comment: yeah thats what i meant

Comment: How did you start the problem? I suggest you draw the graph and find out about the boundary of the region you are to rotate.

Comment: it is rotated over y=-1

Comment: See the example in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_integration#Washer_method

Comment: And this may also be helpful : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration